# How to call helper method in .phtml file

Tags: magento2, phtml, helper

Trying to develop something in magento 2. But, I didn't find how to call a Helper method in template(.phtml) file.

I want a replacement of below code:

```
$this->helper('modulename/helpername')->methodname();
```

If anyone knows please help me.

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: Hey, you should accept Marius's answer below.

Comment: @seanbreeden Sorry, I have up voted, but forgotten to accept.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should not use helper calls directly in the template.
Have your helper instance provided as a dependency to the block that renders the template and create a method in your block that calls the helper and call that method in the template.

Have your block defined like this

```
protected $helperData;
public function __construct(
     ....
    \{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data $helperData,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    ....
}

public function doSomething()
{
    return $this->helperData->doSomething();
}
```

Then you can call in your template `$block->doSomething()`

Comment: Can you please explain what would be the issue if we call helper in template directly without defining in dependency

Comment: it's not a good practice. It introduces an undeclared dependency. If you want to do this properly you should only call in the template only methods from the block that renders it.

Comment: Core magento developer also have called helper directly in phtml file

Comment: That does not make it right. Maybe that part is not get refactored yet

Comment: You  mean to say if I have 10 methods in helper data file, then I should create 10 new methods in block file like you mentioned above?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer, you should not have a helper with 10 methods and all of them are needed for the same block. If that happens maybe you should think about refactoring your code to smaller blocks and templates.

Comment: Late in the action. @GauravAgrawal, you should read on SOLID programming principle.

Comment: What about when we are not using any block? then how to use Helper?

Comment: @Magecode Well... you should always have a block if you need logic in your template.

Comment: To add cancel order from frontend i am directly overriding phtml file by template from extension. for example

<referenceBlock name="sales.order.history">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Packagename_Modulename::order/history.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
i have added this in sales_order_history.xml

In this case i'm not creating any block.

Comment: "It introduces an undeclared dependency."
Whats so bad about a undeclared dependency?

Comment: This looks like alot of pain. I have to extend the block class first each time when I need the helper... I would prefer to call the helper directly.

Comment: Even better.. You van use view models

Answer (score 35):

You have to use like this:

```
$helper = $this->helper('{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data');
$values = $helper->YourHelperMethod();
```

Comment: Yes, its not working. I have also used the same code before

Comment: $this is now deprecated in template logic

Comment: @DominicXigen, You can still use $this though.

Comment: @Black better alternatives. see here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278487/this-deprecated-in-template-logic-whats-the-alternative

Comment: We should not use helper calls directly in the template

Comment: This doesn't work in Magento 2.4.3

Comment: Try with $this->helper('Your Class');

Answer (score 8):

You need to write whole class name in helper as below:

```
$this->helper('vendorename\modulename\Helper\helpername')
```

You can use it in phtml file using above code

Comment: like this will work on m2?

Comment: $this is now deprecated in template logic

Answer (score 2):

> I used this code in one of my module.

**Change Custommodule to NameSpace ( Your company Name)
change ReviewRating to  ( Your Module Name)**

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/Block/HomehorizontalWidget.php`

```
   <?php
namespace Custommodule\ReviewRating\Block;

class HomehorizontalWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

protected $_helper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = [],
    \Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper\Data $helper
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    $this->_helper = $helper;
}

public function getEnable(){
        return $this->_helper->getEnable();
    }

}
```

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/view/frontend/templates/homehorizontalwidget.phtml`

```
 <?php  echo $block->getEnable(); ?>
```

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php 
namespace Custommodule\ReviewRating\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper { 

    /** * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterfac 
        */ 
    protected $_scopeConfig; 
    CONST ENABLE = 'reviewrating/general/enable_module'; 


    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context, 
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig ) {

             parent::__construct($context); $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getEnable(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::ENABLE);
    }

}
```

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Custommodule/ReviewRating/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
system configuration labels created here
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in your Block:

```
protected $helperData;
public function __construct(
     ....
    \{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data $helperData,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    ....
}

public function getHelper()
{
    return $this->helperData;
}
```

And in you template, you can call:

```
$helper = $block->getHelper();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$helper = $this->helper('{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data::class');
$values = $helper->YourHelperMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is by injecting the helper in the block layout as shown in the [magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html). This is called "**Argument Injection**"

Lets say this is your helper method:

#### app/code/Vendor/Module/Helpers/Data.php:

```
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    ...

    public function test($firstParam, $secondParam)
    {
        return "Test successfull p1: $firstParam, p2: $secondParam";
    }
}
```

Just add this inside your block:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
       name="example"
       template="Vendor_Module::mytemplate.phtml">
    
    <arguments>
        <argument name="foo_bar" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::test">
            <param name="firstParam">firstValue123</param>
            <param name="secondParam">secondValue456</param>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Then you can call the helper in the template:

```
/** @var mixed $helperMethodResult */
$helperMethodResult = $block->getData('foo_bar'); // or $block->getFooBar()
```

Now clear the cache `php bin/magento cache:flush` and reload the site where your block is getting loaded.

> **Output**: Test successfull p1: firstValue123, p2: secondValue456

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1.**

> $helper=
> $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->YourMethodName();

You can use above code directly in phtml file.

**Method 2**

Try this code in your Block:

```
protected $helperData;
public function __construct(
     ....
    \{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Data $helperData,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    ....
}

public function getHelper()
{
    return $this->helperData;
}
```

And in you template, you can call:

```
$helper = $block->getHelper();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is dirty and simple, but it works everywhere.

```
$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helper = $objectManager->create(Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::class);
```