# Magento 2: How to Override File in Vendor Folder

Tags: magento2, php, module, third-party-module

I installed a 3rd party PHP sdk via composer and need to override a couple files in my own module. However, I'm not quite sure what the best practice is to override these files from the `vendor` folder.

The 2 files I'm looking to override are located in:

`vendor\quickbooks\v3-php-sdk\src\DataService\DataService.php`

and

`vendor\quickbooks\v3-php-sdk\src\sdk.config`

Here is how the `composer.json` file looks:

```
{
"name": "quickbooks/v3-php-sdk",
"description": "The Official PHP SDK for QuickBooks Online Accounting API",
"type": "library",
"keywords": ["api", "http", "rest", "quickbooks", "smallbusiness"],
"homepage": "http://developer.intuit.com",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "QuickBooksOnline\\API\\": "src/"
    }
},
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "hlu2",
        "email": "Hao_Lu@intuit.com"
    }
]
}
```

My question is, how do I override these 2 files in `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you see on the composer part

```
"name": "quickbooks/v3-php-sdk"
```

and

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "QuickBooksOnline\\API\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

so the path of the vendor folder extension on the vendor, should be in :

`<magento_root>/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/`

then, as the autoload describe in the psr-4 to be like this :

```
"QuickBooksOnline\\API\\": "src/"
```

that's mean you can access class in the folder `quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/*` by defined namespace to be like this :

```
namespace QuickBooksOnline\API;
```

since you want override Class file `vendor\quickbooks\v3-php-sdk\src\DataService\DataService.php` with the my explanation before, so the class should be to be like this :

```
QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\Dataservice
```

to override that class, you just create di.xml inside folder `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/`

add this code to override Dataservice.php Class

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\Dataservice" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Model\DataService" />
</config>
```

the override class now on the `MyCompany\MyModule\Model\DataService.php`

and then to override `sdk.config` I still cannot find to override this xml by similiar xml file again, but as the documentation on this [link](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/40_sdks/03_php/0020_authorization#/section_11) , you can modified the setting on the sdk.config by write php code, in the magento you can create helper file to connect based your setting

so create Helper Class `Data.php` on the folder `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper` add this code to the `Data.php`

```
<?php    
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Helper;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService as DataService;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_dataService;

    public function _construct(
        DataService $dataService
    ){
        $this->_dataService = $dataService;
    }
    public function getConfigurationSetting()
    {
        $settings = $this->_dataService::Configure(array(
        'auth_mode' => 'oauth1',
        'consumerKey' => "ConsumerKey",
        'consumerSecret' => "ConsumerSecret",
        'accessTokenKey' => "CccessTokenKey",
        'accessTokenSecret' => "AccessTokenSecret",
        'QBORealmID' => "RealmID"
        'baseUrl' => "Development/Production"
        ));

        return $settings
    }
}
```

so you can call the method `getConfigurationSetting()` from the helper `Data.php` when you want checking your configuration, you can use [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150941/how-to-call-helper-method-in-phtml-file#answer-150945) to call method on your helper class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, the **Helper/Data** file worked so I'll be able to keep my DataService credentials to a single file!  I'm still stuck on the preference override for `DataService.php`. I've got it all setup, cleared cache but it's still calling from the vendor folder.

Comment: try to execute `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`,  if it still does not work,  please show your new override class code, so we can analyze that

Comment: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` was the trick, thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome,  glad to know it solve your problem :)

Comment: "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Pelago\\": "src/"
        }
    }

I am having only a single namespace *Pelago*. so not able to override. Any idea what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way is to open module's **registration.php** file and check module name there.

So for example your registration file is something like :

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'QuickBooksOnline_API',
     __DIR__
);
```

Then your file path, which you want to extend would be :

`QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService.php`

Comment: Thanks Naveed, I can try this, however it doesn't look like the Quickbooks php library has a `registration.php` file.

Comment: This was just an example how to find file path to extend however in your case you have to extend 'QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService.php' file to extend in your module