# Override vendor file in vendor folder

Tags: magento2

i have created module and overrdie core file now i add my module in vendor but when i add my module in vendor my override file not found

Comment: core file override after you run setup upgrade and depoly command ??

Comment: yup after setup upgrade

Comment: Check this out --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246007/magento-2-how-to-override-file-in-vendor-folder/246018