# Override Extension (/vendor) in app/frontend

Tags: magento2.3, overrides, phtml, vendor, template-override

I'm trying to override a layout .phtml file for a 3rd party extension which is located in `/var/vendor_name/extension`.
As I understand, I should not be modifying the /vendor files, but this extension has no files located in the `app/code` or `app/frontend`.

The file I'm trying to override is located in `<magento_root>/vendor/vendor_name/module_name/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml`

I read through the following thread but I'm not sure how to apply it in my situation [Magento 2: How to Override File in Vendor Folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246007/magento-2-how-to-override-file-in-vendor-folder)

Please let me know if more information needed.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that two ways:

1. Create a module and overwrite the template
2. Copy that template under your current theme

Here is the solution for #2.

1. Create a directory **VendorName_ModuleName** under **app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/**
2. Copy **templates/product/view/list.phtml** to **app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/VendorName_ModuleName/templates/product/view/list.phtml**

Comment: Hi Sohel, thanks for the response. I did as you outlined in #2 and I worked, sort of. The area on my page that I'm trying to modify is now empty so it seem the new file is being recognized. I'm now getting a 500 error and nothing that I put on the new .phtml file will show up in the browser. Could it be because the working directory of the file has changed and some of the previous file/class name references are now invalid? Any ideas on how to trouble shoot or more info I can provide. Thanks again!.

Comment: Can you post here the original error from php error_log/system.log/exception.log?

Comment: Hi again, I had made a mistake trying to log something to console and that is why nothing is loading. Your solution #2 worked for me. All I have to do is clear cache and my changes show up. Cheers!