# $this deprecated in template logic. What's the alternative?

Tags: magento2.3, coding-standards

In this https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml you see something like this

`$this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail())`

In code quality checks I see $this in templates is now deprecated

**What's the recommended approach?**

Comment: Check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/150945/76597 In my opinion that's the correct approach

Comment: That's the route I took (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206077/70343) however you have to independently inject each helper which means more work. I wondered whether there was something which you could pass an argument to that basically works in the same way but does use $this context. A helper helper lol. I guess not.

Comment: the correct path is via view_models right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that either extending the block or creating a view model that injects the helper, then exposes proxy methods for the data you want to access would be the correct way to do it.

Using helpers directly in template files is generally frowned upon since you are introducing business logic into the template. This just seems like old ported code from M1, that will be refactored into the new design patterns at some point in the future.

But if you really wanted a function that behaved the same way, you could reimplement it into your block since all the `helper` function does is load the class through object manager, you can find the implementation here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php#L120

Comment: Creating a viewModel is the valid approach if you ask me

Comment: @GosuPrzmak provide example?

Comment: @DominicXigen Here you go bro

Comment: @DominicXigen please change your mark if the answer below helps you :)

Comment: @GosuPrzmak nice and I completely understand your approach

Answer (score 2):

This breaks down into 3 simple steps.

I assume that you are reffering to the contactForm block in the **contact_index_index.xml**

1) In one of your modules or designs create a contact_index_index.xml in your layout folder

For **module**

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout
```

Remeber about setting sequence in module.xml for Customer_Contact

For **design**

```
Vednor/Theme/Magento_Contact/layout
```

contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
              <arguments>
                   <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\Contact</argument>
              </arguments>
        </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

2) Create your ViewModel -> Vendor\Module\ViewModel\Contact.php

Contact.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Helper\Data as ContactHelperData;

class Contact implements ArgumentInterface {

    /** @var ContactHelperData */
    private $contactHelperData;    

    /** @param ContactHelperData */
    public function __construct(ContactHelperData $contactHelperData)
    {
        $this->contactHelperData = $contactHelperData;
    }    

    /** @return ContactHelperData */
    public function getContactHelperData()
    {
        return $this->contactHelperData;
    }
}
```

3) Use the view_model in your template.

Extend old template. Seems you already did it. Do it in anyway you want I will post an example for theme.

Create the file in

```
 Vendor\Theme\Magento_Contact\templates\form.phtml
```

now in your form.phtml

```
/** @var Vendor\Module\ViewModel\Contact $viewModel */
$viewModel = $block->getData('view_model');    
/** @var Magento\Contact\Helper\Data $viewModel */
$helper = $viewModel->getContactHelperData();
```

Bang, that's all :)

Now you can use the helper within the block without worring about the explosion after near future updates :)

Ofc do the text formatting, it's getting late I could made some typos :)

Answer (score 0):

I quite like the original solution

To elaborate in theory

```php
namespace Xigen\Demo\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $helperFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_helperFactory = $helperFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

     /**
     * Get helper singleton
     * @param string $className
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
     * @throws \LogicException
     */
    public function helper($className)
    {
        $helper = $this->_helperFactory->get($className);
        if (false === $helper instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper) {
            throw new \LogicException($className . ' doesn\'t extends Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper');
        }

        return $helper;
    }
}
```

Then in template phtml should be as easy as:

`$block->helper(\Magento\Contact\Helper\Data::class)->getUserEmail()`

Comment: Well tbh I like it also, but nowadays approach is via viewModels and extending blocks should happen only when you want to customize the block cache or rewriting old classes.

Comment: @GosuPrzmak completely agree you've gone with the official approach. However sometimes less is more. With original solution you would not need to inject further classes if for example you are calling from multiple. That's why I think it's a really elegant solution. Although you've provided really well written alternative. I think others will find both suggestions useful.

Comment: This solutions is minimal solution and efective.Its solved my M2 coding standerd issue very quickly. Thanks.